# User preferences are not saved from XPC service

Tags: macos, cocoa, preferences, xpc

In my main app bundle I have supporting XPC service included. App is sandboxed and everything works quite fine, except that when I call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault] setObject:forKey:]` method and than `- synchronize` method from the XPC service app, preferences are not written and data cannot be retrieved next time I need it.

I didn't find anything related to this problem in Apple's documentation, except that the sandboxed app cannot access preferences of other apps. That's all right, I don't need it. XPC service has its own container in ~/Library/Containers, where it should be able to store its own data, I'd suppose. But obviously it's not the case for some reason.

I probably missed something, but cannot find what. Is there anything special which needs to be done (adding some entitlement or so) in order to make this work?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use Group Containers to share the preferences and I have achieved something similar (a non-UI *LSUIElement* app sharing preferences with its conventional Preferences app countpart) using [RMSharedPreferences](https://github.com/realmacsoftware/RMSharedPreferences).

Comment: Adding entitlement com.apple.security.application-groups resolved the issue. However, I'm still wondering why helper app cannot write into its own container when grouping is disabled. I even don't need to have shared preferences between the main app and XPC service...

Comment: @Matthes I'm not sure with XPC I'm afraid as I've never used it.